# C# JsonProperty(PropertyName) Multi dimensional arrays

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, wordpress

I am working on a project that uses a feed from Wordpress V2 api.
It returns a Json similar to the following:

```
{
  "link": "http://website.com.au/seabourns-antarctica-2/",
  "title": {
    "rendered": "Some Title"
  }
}
```

I am able to use:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "link")]
public string Url { get; set; }
```

to assign the first one but I'm not sure if there is an easy way to get the `title.rendered` string.

Something like the following wouldn't work for me:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "title.rendered")]
public string Title { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Title` is not a multi dimensional array. It is an object with one property.
You can define a class for `Title` and use it.

```
public class Obj
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "link")]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "title")]
    public Title Title { get; set; }
}

public class Title 
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "rendered")]
    public class Rendered { get; set; }
}

// Usage:
Console.WriteLine(obj.Url); 
Console.WriteLine(obj.Title.Rendered);
```

Since objects are key-value associative arrays in JSON, you can also deserialize it as `Dictionary<string, string>` if all properties are going to be plain strings. The usability and convenience of the this method approach depends on usage and specific situations:

```
public class Obj
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "link")]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "title")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Title { get; set; }
}

// Usage:
Console.WriteLine(obj.Url); 
Console.WriteLine(obj.Title["rendered"]);
```

Note that in this case this code will result into **runtime** error:

```
Console.WriteLine(obj.Title["notexisting"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class would be like

```
public class Title
{
    public string rendered { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string link { get; set; }
    public Title title { get; set; }
}
```

then to parse this json you should do like this

```
RootObject obj = JsonConvert.Deserailize<RootObject>("jsonString");
```